# PDF reader not working

Tags: pdf, reader

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.nio.file.Files;

    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;
`    
public class Test{


    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {

        String  pdf= "c:\\sample.pdf";

         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);

    }


}
```

it not working 
like it should i am running windows
need help please help i tried a lot of things but still getting the same message

here is the error message

this is the output i get when i tried ur code

File Exists: true

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:148)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj(PdfReader.java:1024)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1430)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:732)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
at pdfconverter.Test.main(Test.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Please use the [edit] link under the question and include this information.  Also detail what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good to me. Perhaps more information on the error you are having? For instance, it could be a classpath error - something like the itextpdf classes not being located...

In case it helps as a baseline - the following code works for me. I removed the extraneous includes, though they won't hurt to leave them in.

```
import java.io.File;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String  pdf= "C:\\Java-Design-Patterns.pdf";

        try {
            System.out.println("File Exists: "+new File(pdf).exists());
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            int count = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println("PDF has "+count+" pages.");
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to open PDF ["+pdf+"]: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
File Exists: true
PDF has 183 pages.
```

The itext jar I used is: itextpdf-5.5.12.jar (included via [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.12)).

The pdf I used (courtesy of google: java design patterns pdf) is here: http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/java/naited/Java-Design-Patterns.pdf
I haven't read it yet, but the first page looks good ;)

That said, [itextpdf](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java) is quite awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable
```

clearly indicates the issue: Bouncy Castle is missing! (Or at least the required version is missing.)

Bouncy Castle is a library used by iText for encryption, decryption, signing, and signature verification, [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org) their web representation.

Thus, add the Bouncy Castle libraries to your class path. Please be aware, though, that the BC version required depends on the iText version in question. The maven link you provided for your itext7 version indicates that BC 1.49 is required.